# mlogit : impossible to coerce the choice variable to a logical

Tags: r, mlogit

I have created an artificial data for mlogit with each person given 4 choices in two sets. However I am getting `impossible to coerce the choice variable to a logical` error while trying to apply the model.

I have seen the following link but it is not solving my case. Not able to understand the reason properly. Can you please help.

[R Mlogit Error in replacement rows and impossible to coerce choice variable to logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64746745/r-mlogit-error-in-replacement-rows-and-impossible-to-coerce-choice-variable-to-l)

My data looks like this :

[image]

Data I am using :

```
dput( df1 )
structure(list(Alternative = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Choice = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L), 
    B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), H = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L), I = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code

```
model = mlogit( Choice ~ B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I | 0, data = df1, 
               
               alt.var = 'Alternative', 
               
               shape = "long")
```

Error :

```
Error in dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index = dfa$drop.index,  : 
  impossible to coerce the choice variable to a logical
```

Comment: Before running the model, try transforming the `Choice` column in `df1` from `integer` to `logical`, via `as.logical()`.

Comment: Once I do it, I am getting the following error : `Error in if (abs(x - oldx) < ftol) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Did you try `library(tidyverse)` and `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Choice = as.logical(Choice))`?  If you did that, and it still failed, then it looks like [`mlogit` is to blame](https://community.rstudio.com/t/mlogit-data-fails-for-latest-version-of-mlogit-package/23507).

Comment: Are _all_ these fields expected to be `logical`?

Comment: Yes I tried this. No all fields are not expected to be logical. They can stay numeric.

Comment: You could look at the dfidx function source code (around line 442) to reason about the error